# Cannot install anything from apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, apt-get

Everytime I try to install any package from the package manager, I get the following error

```
 liblua5.2-0 : Breaks: liblua5.2-0:i386 (!= 5.2.4-1ubuntu1) but 5.2.0-2 is to be installed
 liblua5.2-0:i386 : Breaks: liblua5.2-0 (!= 5.2.0-2) but 5.2.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run sudo apt-get -f install I get

```
Preparing to unpack .../liblua5.2-0_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking liblua5.2-0:i386 (5.2.4-1ubuntu1) over (5.2.0-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liblua5.2-0_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/liblua5.2-0/copyright', which is different from other instances of package liblua5.2-0:i386
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/liblua5.2-0_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried various things such as clearing out the cache and installing from the package manager and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` for a visual interface that will help you to diagnose what exactly goes wrong. The interface takes some time get used to, so don't get impatient and look around a bit first, and there's help to explain the keyboard commands.

As this error shows up for any package you try to install, it means your current configuration is inconsistent. When you start `aptitude` (as root), you should see a message that something is wrong, and there's a screen that gives you possible suggestions how to fix it (key `!` "to examine"). Sometimes these suggestions work out, sometimes it is better to manually upgrade some packages to make the problem go away. In your case, that would be packages related to "lua" (key `/` to search for packages). Key `i` to install/upgrade a package, key `b` to jump to the next "broken" package. Key `g` to execute your choices.

Depending on the situation, it may take some fiddling before all broken packages are resolved. Also, first do an update (`u`) of available packages.

Comment: I don't aptitude on my machine I guess. I though that came standard?

Comment: Looked it up: It was standard till Ubuntu 10.10, and still is for the server variant. You can still try: (1) Install aptitude manually (`apt-get --download-only`, `dpkg -i` on `.deb` file), (2) Try to remove the offending package `liblua5.2-0`, take note of what other packages that will remove, install aptitude and install those packages later, (3) `apt-get install -f` with various lua-related package names that should be upgraded, in the hope you hit the right combination.

Comment: I figured it out :) No idea why the system was unable to overwrite the documentation, but removing it first solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by running the following command in /usr/share/doc/liblua5.2-0

```
rm -f *
```

I then ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

The problem has been fixed.